# Creating a Reusable UITableView using storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboard, iboutlet

I have a UITableView that I will be using in multiple spots. The tableview's data does not change at all, it's the exact same one, but in different parts of the app.

I have created a custom class just for the tableview. I will adding my table views using a storyboard. Do I just hook up my table views to same IBOutlet each time I want to use my table view class?

Comment: I think you might want to make one table view, put it in a child view controller, and then embed this child everywhere you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a class for the `UITableView`, then in the storyboard when you want to use it just drag in a `UITableView` to the storyboard and change the class in the identity inspector to the name of your custom class.

To retain the same data, you can setup this data in the `init` of the table view so that it is the same across all instances.

Alternatively, you could perhaps store a single table view instance as a static property on your table view class and then add it to your view hierarchy in your view controllers. This, however, may not be best practice.

Comment: That won't copy the data from the storyboard between view controllers.